# Copy image to new directory and rename - Java

Tags: java, json, image, copy, rename

So far I have a list of images and I want to rename them based on information I get from a database.

List of images:

```
IBImages = ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3"]

private static void buildTheme(ArrayList<String> IBImages) {
    String bundlesPath = "/a/long/path/with/dest/here";

    for (int image = 0; image < IBImages.size(); image++) {
        String folder = bundlesPath + "/" + image;
        File destFolder = new File(folder);
        // Create a new folder with the image name if it doesn't already exist
        if (!destFolder.exists()) {
            destFolder.mkdirs();
            // Copy image here and rename based on a list returned from a database.
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON you get from the database might look something like this. I want to rename the one image that I have to all of the names in the list of icon_names

```
{
    "icon_name": [
            "Icon-40.png",
            "Icon-40@2x.png",
            "Icon-40@3x.png",
            "Icon-Small.png",
            "Icon-Small@2x.png",
    ]
}
```

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is. Do you want to know how to rename a file in java?

Comment: I'm trying to copy a file from one location to another and rename the image.

Comment: Yes, but what's the problem? What have you tried? Why is not working? Btw., have a look at [`java.nio.file.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: I haven't tried much of anything. I'm still reasonably new to Java but I have other programming experience. I'm trying how someone might take an image in a folder and copy x amount of times, where x is the number of strings in a list. So I may want to take a picture names Facebook.png, copy it to a new folder 11 times and rename it 11 times (each time it would get renamed different based on the string names in a list). I'm looking to see how someone might accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have into directory few files with same name at once. You need to either copy your file once and rename it, or create empty file with new name and copy bits from original file into it. Second approach is quite easy with `Files` class and its [`copy(source, target, copyOptions...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) method.

Here is simple example of copying one file located in `images/source/image.jpg` to new files in `image/target` directory while giving them new names.

```
String[] newNames = { "foo.jpg", "bar.jpg", "baz.jpg" };

Path source = Paths.get("images/source/image.jpg"); //original file
Path targetDir = Paths.get("images/target"); 

Files.createDirectories(targetDir);//in case target directory didn't exist

for (String name : newNames) {
    Path target = targetDir.resolve(name);// create new path ending with `name` content
    System.out.println("copying into " + target);
    Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    // I decided to replace already existing files with same name
}
```